# JavaScript: find all occurrences of substrings' indices in a string

Tags: javascript

I need to write a function that is going to take a string and an array of substrings. and I need to add some HTML tag to wrap the substrings in the string. If two such substrings overlap, I should wrap them together with only one pair of tag.

The first thing I need to do is to get the start indices and end indices of where a substring occurs in the string. For example:

```js
const str = 'aabc'
const target = ['aa', 'bc']
```

I need to be able to know that the indices for the substrings are `[[0,2], [2,4]]` where the start index is inclusive and the end index is exclusive.

Here is my attempt

```js
function findOccurrances(str, words) {
  return words.map((word) => [
    str.indexOf(word),
    str.indexOf(word) + word.length,
  ])
}
```

However, if `target` is `['a', 'bc']`, the result should be `[[0, 1], [1,2], [2,4]` but since `indexOf` only returns the first occurrence of the substring, we only get `[[0, 1], [2,4]` as the result using my function.

I wonder what are some ways to achieve this?

Comment: SO you need to loop more that once and use the offset `indexOf(searchElement, fromIndex)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Seems about right

```js
const str = 'aabc'
const target = ['aa', 'bc']

function findOccurances(str, words) {
  const list = []
  str.split('').forEach((c,i) => {
    words.forEach(t => {
      if (str.substr(i, t.length) === t) {
        list.push([i, i + t.length])
      }
    })
  })
  return list
}

console.log(findOccurances(str, target))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. What is the time complexity for this?

Comment: O (n^2) ... anything with nested loop... which is all the answers here I believe. If it is a forEach, indexOf, map, etc its a loop... as these are not free.

Answer (score 0):

You could combine `reduce` with another recursive inner function and in each call pass remaining word text.

```js
function findOccurrances(str, words) {
  const f = (word, rest, last = 0) => {
    const result = []
    const index = rest.indexOf(word)

    if (index != -1) {
      result.push([last + index, last + index + word.length])
      result.push(...f(word, rest.slice(index + 1), last + index + 1))
    }

    return result;
  }

  return words.reduce((r, e) => {
    r.push(...f(e, str))
    return r;
  }, [])
}

console.log(findOccurrances('aabc', ['a', 'bc']))
console.log(findOccurrances('aabc', ['bc', 'aa']))
console.log(findOccurrances('azzz', ['zz']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a `String.stringIndex` method which takes a substring  as parameter  , finds the start and end index of substring in the parent string . Finally ,  returning an array of start and end indexes. Using this method i created a function which you can use to get the results as you expect !

```
 String.prototype.stringIndex = function(t) {
    t = Array.from(t);
    let start_index = this.indexOf(t[0]);
    let end_index = this.slice(start_index + 1, this.length);
    if (t.length == 1) {
      end_index = start_index;
    } else {
      let increment = start_index + 1 ;
      end_index = end_index.indexOf(t[t.length - 1]) + increment;
    }
    return [start_index,
      end_index];
  }

  function findOccurrances(string, words) {
    return words.map((word) => string.stringIndex(word));
  }

  console.log(findOccurrances("i love chocolates", ["love", "chocolates"]));
```